# Unreadable characters in programs (graphic glitch)

Tags: graphics, display

A picture is worth a thousand words...

Screenshot (gVim) -

[image]

Screenshot (LibreOffice) -

[image]

The Appearance Preferences dialog -

[image]

Anyone know what causes it and how it can be fixed?

If it's relevant - the system runs on an AMD Turion and a GeForce Go 6100. I have a feeling it's got something to do with video memory. Although I could be wrong.

Comment: Can you post the output of `locale` ?

Comment: Posted output of locale

Comment: Does it happens with another themes too (besides Orta and Orty)?

Comment: That certainly looks like an issue with a graphics card... Corrupted video memory. It's not an issue with the font renderer, because the problem clearly isn't just limited to fonts. Does changing the contents of a window (e.g. by changing some text, resizing it, or selecting a different item) fix the issue temporarily? Does the garbled mess change to another garbled mess?

Comment: If you have any propriety drivers installed for your graphics card try disabling them.

If not, try searching for and enabling them if they exist.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue, this might help:

First, check in Jockey that your graphic card's driver is up and running - sometimes it will show a green light but say "not in use". If that is the case, you need to completely purge you graphic cards driver and then re-install.

I recommend *not* using jockey to install as, for some reason, that was what led to the bug for me.

See this thread on the ubuntu forums for more information regarding your graphics card and how to purge/re-install the drivers:

[Forum post: Nvidia driver activated but not currently in use (11.04)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1743386&page=4)

PS: I would recommend reinstalling your graphic drivers even if jockey says it is fine, it seems like a gpu issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem or not, but I had a refresh problem with gVim when I was using Compiz until I did the following: Open CompizConfig Settings Manager (`ccsm`), then enable the Workarounds plugin, and in its setting, check the box for "Qt Window Fix".

Comment: Workarounds was already enabled. I've just checked the box for Qt. Will report back after testing inshaAllah.

Comment: It didn't work. Just started having the same problem.